# Remove foreground view from FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-framelayout

I'm using the following command to draw a border on a frameLayout:

```
frameLayout.setForeground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_border));
```

Now I want to remove this foreground drawable.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass null as parameter should be enough:

```
frameLayout.setForeground(null);
```

Comment: Just faster on the trigger than me. :(

Comment: call requires API 23...

Comment: Hardly since it was available in api v1. Double check the documentation